# Styled Components do not pass dom attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

i'm new in `styled-components` i use it un `react` and `typescript` project.

I use a styled component `StyledButton` which is created with `styled.button` but when i pass the attribute `disabled={true}` at my top level component, it is not display in the dom render. The style is well render (when disable button is grey) but the prop `disabled` is not pass to the dom element button (so it's still clickable...)

**Button.style.ts:**

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { fontFamily, fontSize, fontWeight, getSpacing } from '../../stylesheet';

interface StyledButtonProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  fullWidth?: boolean;
  backgroundColor: string;
  textColor: string;
  borderColor?: string;
  borderRadiusProp: string;
}

export const StyledButton = styled.button<StyledButtonProps>(props => ({
  cursor: 'pointer',
  height: '45px',
  borderRadius: props.borderRadiusProp,
  ...((props.fullWidth ?? false) && {
    width: '100%',
  }),
  padding: '12px 24px',
  color: props.textColor,
  background: props.backgroundColor,
  textAlign: 'center',
  ...(props.borderColor ?? ''
    ? {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: props.borderColor,
      }
    : {
        border: 'none',
      }),
  ':hover': {
    backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor,
  },
}));

export const ButtonContent = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: ${fontFamily.main};
  font-size: ${fontSize.medium};
  font-weight: ${fontWeight.large};
  margin-right: ${getSpacing(4)};
  margin-left: ${getSpacing(4)};
`;
```

**Button.tsx :**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { borderRadius } from 'stylesheet';
import { ButtonContent, StyledButton } from './Button.style';

export interface ButtonProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  fullWidth?: boolean;
  borderRadiusProp?: string;
  backgroundColor: string;
  textColor: string;
  borderColor?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Button = ({
  onClick,
  fullWidth,
  borderRadiusProp = borderRadius.m,
  backgroundColor,
  textColor,
  borderColor,
  disabled = false,
  children,
}: ButtonProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <StyledButton
      disabled={disabled}
      onClick={onClick}
      fullWidth={fullWidth}
      borderColor={borderColor}
      borderRadiusProp={borderRadiusProp}
      backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
      textColor={textColor}
    >
      <ButtonContent>{children}</ButtonContent>
    </StyledButton>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

**GradientButton.tsx:**

```js
import Button from 'components/Button/Button';
import React from 'react';
import { borderRadius, colorUsage, gradientColors } from 'stylesheet';

interface GradientButtonProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> {
  fullWidth?: boolean;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  disabled?: boolean;
  gradient?: keyof typeof gradientColors;
}

export const getColorBackground = (gradients: string[], disabled?: boolean): string => {
  if (disabled ?? false) return colorUsage.buttonDisabled;
  return `linear-gradient(90deg, ${gradients[0]} -27.6%, ${gradients[1]} 111.77%);`;
};

export const getTextColor = (disabled?: boolean): string => {
  if (disabled ?? false) return colorUsage.buttonDisabledText;
  return colorUsage.buttonPrimaryTextColor;
};

const GradientButton = ({
  children,
  gradient = 'blue',
  disabled = false,
  ...rest
}: GradientButtonProps): JSX.Element => {
  const backgroundGradient = getColorBackground(gradientColors[gradient], disabled);
  const textColor = getTextColor(disabled);

  return (
    <Button
      borderRadiusProp={borderRadius.s}
      backgroundColor={backgroundGradient}
      textColor={textColor}
      disabled={disabled}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
};

export default GradientButton;
```

**file where i call my button:**

```js
  <GradientButton
      id="login-form-button"
      gradient="blue"
      type="submit"
      disabled={!isValid || isEmpty(touched)}
      fullWidth
   >
       Login
   </GradientButton>
```

Comment: what happens if disabled is true by default? does it show as disabled?

Comment: with `disabled` default true, it works but i don't know why

Comment: could you check this minimal reproduction? https://codesandbox.io/s/button-disabled-attr-sc-kfdfc it is working there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you mentioned with the `disabled` set to **true** (hardcoded) it works, this means button is rendered correctly, the issue seems to be with

> disabled={!isValid || isEmpty(touched)}

The condition might never evaluate to true hence the button is never disabled.  Recheck this condition and it should work as expected.